# Enterprise channel not working

Tags: magento-connect, cli

When trying to update some modules I'm getting this

```
$ sudo -u mysudouser ./mage list-upgrades

PHP Warning:  array_combine(): Both parameters should have at least 1 element in /chroot/home/conairin/conairindustries.com/html/downloader/lib/Mage/Connect/Rest.php on line 242
PHP Warning:  ksort() expects parameter 1 to be array, boolean given in /chroot/home/conairin/conairindustries.com/html/downloader/lib/Mage/Connect/Rest.php on line 243

list-upgrades: Access denied for @https://connect20.magentocommerce.com/enterprise/packages.xml
```

When I run

```
$ sudo -u mysudouser ./mage list-installed
```

I get quite a few extensions installed under

```
Installed package for channel 'enterprise' :
```